# Why can I not interpolate even though the values are monotonically increasing?

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation

I have 2 arrays that I plot this way:

```
plt.plot(x1, x2)
```

[image]

And I want to find out what are the values of `x2` at `x1=2,5,75,10,100, and 1000`. Since all values may not exist, I interpolate using this:

```
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
f1=interp1d(x1, x2)
f2=interp1d(x1, x2, kind='cubic')
```

But `f2` throws this error:

`ValueError: Expect x to be a 1-D sorted array_like.`

But the values are monotonically increasingly as expected by: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html

What am I doing wrong?

`x1`

```
array([1.00020004e+00, 1.00020004e+00, 1.00080064e+00, 1.00200401e+00,
       1.00341160e+00, 1.00603622e+00, 1.01173614e+00, 1.02165917e+00,
       1.02965404e+00, 1.04362346e+00, 1.05820106e+00, 1.07688994e+00,
       1.10107906e+00, 1.12688754e+00, 1.16063138e+00, 1.19161106e+00,
       1.23578843e+00, 1.29198966e+00, 1.35062129e+00, 1.42775557e+00,
       1.52207002e+00, 1.63345312e+00, 1.77746178e+00, 1.93124759e+00,
       2.11954218e+00, 2.37191651e+00, 2.68528464e+00, 2.97973778e+00,
       3.38983051e+00, 3.89105058e+00, 4.48430493e+00, 5.31349628e+00,
       6.28930818e+00, 7.59878419e+00, 9.38086304e+00, 1.20192308e+01,
       1.57232704e+01, 2.06611570e+01, 2.68817204e+01, 3.49650350e+01,
       4.58715596e+01, 6.57894737e+01, 8.92857143e+01, 1.38888889e+02,
       2.27272727e+02, 4.16666667e+02, 1.00000000e+03, 2.50000000e+03,
       2.50000000e+03, 5.00000000e+03])
```

`x2`

```
array([ 11.18083778,  12.00065196,  12.88057749,  13.82502193,
        14.838716  ,  15.92673731,  17.09453577,  18.34796088,
        19.69329106,  21.13726508,  22.68711581,  24.35060647,
        26.1360695 ,  28.05244828,  30.10934199,  32.31705361,
        34.68664159,  37.22997521,  39.95979405,  42.88977178,
        46.0345847 ,  49.40998519,  53.03288065,  56.9214182 ,
        61.09507555,  65.57475857,  70.38290604,  75.54360201,
        81.08269642,  87.02793465,  93.40909644, 100.25814508,
       107.6093875 , 115.49964612, 123.96844331, 133.05819935,
       142.81444487, 153.28604899, 164.52546404, 176.58898835,
       189.53704818, 203.43450047, 218.35095766, 234.36113639,
       251.54523176, 269.98931903, 289.78578477, 311.03378962,
       333.83976499, 358.31794618])
```

Comment: is it possible that the splin cubic is not working because in x1 you have equal values (for example the two first ones)? from the doc it should make sens because of the way they interpolate

Comment: The digits that we can see of the first two values of `x1` are the same.  If those two values are actually the same, then `x1` is not *strictly* monotonically increasing.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Agreed. I didn't notice them. And didn't make the distinction between `monotonically increasing` and `strictly monotonically increasing`. Is there an alternative method for my data?

Comment: So you do have repeated `x1` values with *different* `x2` values?  What do you expect an interpolator to do with such data?    That is, what should the interpolator return at one of those repeated values of `x1`?

Answer (score 1):

The test it's doing it is:

```
np.any(x1[1:] <= x1[:-1])
```

notice the `<=`, which means equal values (like: 2.50000000e+03,, 2.50000000e+03) in your array will cause errors.

Changing these and (there's two more at the start of the array) will make the error go away.

I *not* sure this is the right way to go about dealing with your data, but you could delete the dupes (and corresponding x2 values) with something like:

```
x3, ind = np.unique(x1, return_index = True)
x4 = x2[ind] 
f2=interp1d(x3, x4, kind='cubic')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Unfortunately, I can't change these values itself, since they are a part of my computation. Is there an alternative interpolation technique for non-linear data that doesn't have this limitation.

Comment: you can add/substract epsilon to the repeated values, it will not affect the results but they will no longer be equal

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki Could you please explain as an answer, please? I am not sure how to.

Comment: It's not clear what *should* happen here when you have the same x1 corresponding to a different x2.

Comment: You could delete them @maximusdooku -- not sure if that's appropriate. See edit

Answer (score 1):

Just add this two lines before doing the interpolation:

```
x1[0] -= 0.0000001
x1[-2] += 0.0000001
```

Looks like with epsilon does not work

Comment: This solution won't scale for me, as I will be doing this over thousands of arrays. And I don't know which indices will be repeated in advance.

Comment: Then you will need to iterate over the values and when you see repeated ones apply this